# SQL sum and previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, sum

I have the following table:

```
________________________
date        |  amount
________________________
01-01-2019  | 10
01-01-2019  | 10
01-01-2019  | 10
01-01-2019  | 10
02-01-2019  |  5
02-01-2019  |  5
02-01-2019  |  5
02-01-2019  |  5
03-01-2019  | 20
03-01-2019  | 20
```

These are mutation values by date. I would like my query to return the summed amount by date. So for 02-01-2019 I need 40 ( 4 times 10) + 20 ( 4 times 5). For 03-01-2019 I would need ( 4 times 10) + 20 ( 4 times 5) + 40 ( 2 times 20) and so on. Is this possible in one query? How do I achieve this?

My current query to get the individual mutations:

```sql
Select s.date,
  Sum(s.amount) As Sum_amount
From dbo.Financieel As s
Group By s.date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below script to get your desired output-

```
SELECT A.date,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM <your_table> WHERE Date <= A.Date) C_Total
FROM <your_table> A
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Output is-

```
date        C_Total
01-01-2019  40
02-01-2019  60
03-01-2019  100
```

Comment: Not sure what `CTE` is in this query as it is never defined, most likely you meant to write a co-related subquery like `(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM <your_table> B WHERE B.Date <= A.Date) C_Total`

Comment: That will be table name in place of CTE. CTE remains there as I have tested the script using a CTE :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3192d78ee1d86ffafe5b29934715c2f1)**

```
select dateval,
SUM(amt) OVER(ORDER BY dateval ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as amt
from
(
    SELECT 
    dateval, 
    SUM(amount) amt
FROM t2  group by dateval
)A
```

OUTPUT:

```
dateval              amt
01/01/2019 00:00:00  40
01/02/2019 00:00:00  60
01/03/2019 00:00:00  100
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a window  function, like this:

```
select date, sum(amount) over( order by date)
from table
```